# after flashing cache files magento 2 showing 500 Error

Tags: magento-2.1

After flashing cache Static files under admin -> cache management in magento 2 showing 500 Error and vendor folder got automatically deleted during this process. I don't know why it happend.

They shown me following error.

Vendor autoload is not found. Please run 'composer install' under application root directory.

Kindly suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change https://packages.magento.com/ to https://repo.magento.com/ ?

in composer.json

The first one was the old URL. You should remove that from your 
composer.json (Magento Root) and add second one.

Comment: Its already showing in file. "type": "composer","url": "https://repo.magento.com/". i dont know why after click on flash static file page goes blank and it display above error.  also my vendor folder got deleted.

Comment: Magento 2 version?

Comment: css and js is not loading after above problem solved.kindly help me

Comment: Could you please let me know the URL that you are getting in console? for css and js (404)